# Android : Optimize custom view loading time

Tags: java, android, android-webview, mathjax

I am using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) from [this link](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView) for my calculator app. It's basiclaly a custom view that uses MathJax.

Everything is running smoothly except the loading time of the custom view.
It has a lag of about a second before being properly displayed.

I have searched through google and tried out various ways to optimize a web view but its not of much use.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

MathJax is kind of heavy for mobile environment. `MathView` now add an alternative rendering engine called [KaTeX](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX). Try update the dependency version to `0.0.3`, and set the attribute `auto:engine="KaTeX"`. It should be faster now. For more details, check this [link](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView).

Comment: Sounds interesting, will definitely give it a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: But KaTex does not provide automatic line breaking